# Is it possible to get artifact from AppVeyor failed job?

Tags: python, swig, appveyor

I am trying to use AppVeyor as my CI for testing builds of [M2Crypto](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/) and currently whole build process [fails](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/mcepl/m2crypto-6gp50/build/1.0.35/job/t653615hx134849o). Unfortunately, the main C file of the project [SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/blob/master/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c) is generated by [SWIG](http://www.swig.org). For analysis of the issues with build I would need to see this generated C file. However, it seems to me that artefacts (defined in my [appveyor.yml](https://gitlab.com/mcepl/m2crypto/blob/appveyor/appveyor.yml)) is made available only with a successful build. Is it possible to allow access to these artefacts even from failed builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push artifact [from script](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/#pushing-artifacts-from-scripts) and set this script at `on_finish` or `on_failure` stage of [build pipeline](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#build-pipeline)